# How to fit data known up to a proportionality constant using NonlinearModelFit?

Tags: programming

Referring to my last question here  [Problem with NonlinearModelFit in the case of ODE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/279009/problem-with-nonlinearmodelfit-in-the-case-of-ode/279069?noredirect=1#comment697019_279069)

I am still looking for your help in solving the data-fitting problem where the data are only known up to a proportionality constant k. See the code attached where the plot of the fitting is so bad when we aim to fit k*data instead of data.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
 data = {{0, 107}, {1, 135}, {2, 612}, {3, 195}, {4,
    626}, {5, 619}, {6, 491}, {7, 1164}, {8, 1137}, {9, 511}, {10, 
   1036}, {11, 1144}, {12, 2650}, {13, 3162}, {14, 6074}, {15, 
   6693}, {16, 8253}, {17, 6639}, {18, 6148}, {19, 4345}, {20, 
   3141}, {21, 1958}, {22, 1130}, {23, 484}, {24, 356}, {25, 
   296}, {26, 195}, {27, 121}, {28, 208}, {29, 101}, {30, 67}, {31, 
   128}, {32, 20}};(*initial values of infections*)
model[\[Gamma]_?NumericQ, \[Beta]_?NumericQ, s0_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ] := 
  NDSolveValue[{s'[t] == -\[Beta] i[t]*s[t], 
                i'[t] == -(\[Gamma]) i[t] + \[Beta] i[t]*s[t],
                 s[0] == s0,  i[0] == k*data[[1, 2]]}, {s, i}, {t, 0, 33}][[2]];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[k*data, model[\[Gamma], \[Beta], s0, k][t], {\[Gamma], \[Beta], s0, k}, t, Method -> "LevenbergMarquardt"]
par = nlm["BestFitParameters"]
{tmin, tmax} = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]];
Show[ListPlot[data], 
 Plot[nlm[t], {t, tmin, tmax}, PlotStyle -> Orange], Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Any help is gratefully received. Thanks.

Comment: Note that `k*data` gets you `{{0, 107 k}, {k, 135 k}, {2 k, 612 k}, {3 k, 195 k},...` which is not what I think you want.  If the model is "off" by a proportion, then that would be modeled by  `p  * model[\[Gamma], \[Beta], s0, k][t]` where `p` is the proportionality parameter.  In short, I'm not clear on what you want.  Is it the data or the model that is off by a proportional amount?  In any event, `p` would need to be associated with the model rather than the data.

Comment: Dear @JimB, thanks for your comment. Right, we want to fit the second part of data corresponding to the infectious up to a proportional constant k, since we do not want everyone to go to the hospital.

Comment: But this is this not the same question?  If so, why did you open up the same question?  Or how is this question different?